# Is there a way to export a few animations using same figure in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, figure

I have got few animation.FuncAnimation based on the same plt.figure(), I would like to export them to one animation(video) in matplotlib to improve graphics visualization.

I have already done research in this field in the internet but I did not find anything useful.

```py
self.ax, self.voxels = None, None
self.fig = plt.figure()

# Creating the Animation object
lenght_1 = 10
lenght_2 = 15
self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update, lenght_1, interval=650, blit=False, repeat=True)
self.ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update_2nd, lenght_2, interval=650, blit=False, repeat=True)
```

```py
    def update(self, num):
        """
        The function which update the plot for every frame
        :param num: iterations
        :return: plot animation
        """
        self.ax.cla()
        elev = self.elevators[0]
        point = elev.shortest_path
        floor, row, col = point[num]

        self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = '#ff99ff'
        self.fcolors_2 = self.explode(self.facecolors)

        self.voxels = self.ax.voxels(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.filled_2,
                                     facecolors=self.fcolors_2, edgecolors=self.ecolors_2)
        if [floor, row, col] == elev.DESTINATION:
            self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = '#ff99ff4D'
        elif [row, col] != ElevatorConst.SHAFT_DESC and [row, col] != ElevatorConst.SHAFT_ASC:
            self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = '#1f77b430'
        else:
            if [row, col] == ElevatorConst.SHAFT_DESC:
                color = '#00140d33'
                self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = color
            else:
                color = '#ffffff33'
                self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = color

    def update_2nd(self, num):
        """
        The function which update the plot for every frame
        :param num: iterations
        :return: plot animation
        """
        self.ax.cla()
        elev = self.elevators[1]
        point = elev.shortest_path
        floor, row, col = point[num]

        self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = '#49fdb8'
        self.fcolors_2 = self.explode(self.facecolors)

        self.voxels = self.ax.voxels(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.filled_2,
                                     facecolors=self.fcolors_2, edgecolors=self.ecolors_2)
        if [floor, row, col] == elev.DESTINATION:
            self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = '#49fdb84D'
        elif [row, col] != ElevatorConst.SHAFT_DESC and [row, col] != ElevatorConst.SHAFT_ASC:
            self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = '#1f77b430'
        else:
            if [row, col] == ElevatorConst.SHAFT_DESC:
                color = '#00140d33'
                self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = color
            else:
                color = '#ffffff33'
                self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = color
```

**NEW UPDATE FUNC:**

```py
    def try_update(self, num):
        """
        The function which update the plot for every frame
        :param num: iterations
        :return: plot animation
        """

        for elev in self.elevators:
            self.ax.cla()
            point = elev.shortest_path
            if num < len(point):
                floor, row, col = point[num]

                self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = ElevatorColors.ELEVATOR[elev.id]
                self.fcolors_2 = self.explode(self.facecolors)
                self.voxels = self.ax.voxels(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.filled_2,
                                             facecolors=self.fcolors_2, edgecolors=self.ecolors_2)

                if [floor, row, col] == elev.DESTINATION:
                    self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = ElevatorColors.DESTINATION[elev.id]
                elif [row, col] != ElevatorConst.SHAFT_DESC and [row, col] != ElevatorConst.SHAFT_ASC:
                    self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = ElevatorColors.PATH
                else:
                    if [row, col] == ElevatorConst.SHAFT_DESC:
                        color = ElevatorColors.SHAFT_DESC
                        self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = color
                    else:
                        color = ElevatorColors.SHAFT_ASC
                        self.facecolors[row][col][floor] = color
```

At the end I would like to have exported animation(video) which shows my code visualization.

Comment: There should only ever be *one* FuncAnimation. Once you have this one animation you can simply save it via `ani.save(...)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest not in my case, because of lenght_1 and lenght_2 they are number of iteration for animation update, they are different. If I combined them both, it would appear index error

Comment: Yes you need to completely change the `update` function (which isn't shown here, so no help possible).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest updated

Comment: That is not self-contained enough to use it for an answer. But it looks like there is a lot of overlap between the two functions, so the bit that needs to be managed separately would be small, possibly one `if num > ...:` is enough.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Would that bit be in update function?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will upload more code later

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i have added my new update function but now few steps will be made and then plot disappear ://

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest comment updated

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i can gibe u an access to my privater repo, but priv

Comment: Sorry, I have no interest to look through some hundreds of codelines in a private repo.

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot run the code from the question, so all I can do is to show the concept.
Instead of two `FuncAnimation`s which are in competition to each other, one needs to stick with a single animation.

```
def update_1(num):
    # code for the first animation

def update_2(num):
    # code for the second animation

def update_all(num):
    ax.clear()
    if num < max1:
       update_1(num)
    else:
       update_1(max1)

    # the second animation is assumed to always take `num`
    update_2(num)


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_all, frames=max2)
```

Comment: its not about full code, cos it is a big one, it is working as it should but ax.clear() ruin my work. Cos colors of elements are being changed. Maybe the solution is to place ax.clear() in correct place or change it. I have color with alpha transparency.

Comment: Your task when asking a question here would be to reduce the full code to a [mcve]. At this point I can't help more, sorry.